# Highscore with rank and unique user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to get an Highscore list with unique users.
Having issues with the unique part. By removing GROUP BY the script doesn't contain errors

DATABASE:

```
GameResult
Id, GameId, TicketId,   Score,  Email,          Extra,  CreatedTime
1   1       1           100     test@test.com   info1   2012-12-01T12:12:12
2   1       2           200     test2@test.com  info2   2014-01-01T01:01:01
3   1       3           300     test3@test.com  info3   2013-05-01T05:05:05

Ticket
Id, UserId, TicketNumber,   ControlCode
1   1       abc1            123
2   1       abc2            234
3   2       abc3            345

User
Id, UniqueUserId
1   555
2   666
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
  g1.*, t1.UserId, t1.ControlCode, t1.TicketNumber, u1.UniqueUserId
FROM [dbo].[GameResult] as g1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ticket] as t1
      ON (g1.TicketId = t1.Id)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] as u1
    ON (t1.UserId = u1.Id)
GROUP BY u1.UniqueUserId 
ORDER BY g1.Score Desc, g1.CreatedTime Asc
```

ERROR:

```
Column 'dbo.GameResult.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

WANTED RESULT:

```
Rank    GameResult.Id,  GameId, TicketId,   Score,  Email,          Extra,  CreatedTime,            UserId, TicketNumber,   ControlCode,    UniqueUserId
1       3               1       3           300     test3@test.com  info3   2013-05-01T05:05:05     2       abc3            345             666
2       2               1       2           200     test2@test.com  info2   2014-01-01T01:01:01     1       abc2            234             555
```

Comment: What is the issue you have when trying to use GROUP BY?   Do you get an error, and if so, what is the error message?   As currently written, I have no idea what your actual question is.

Comment: Which version of MS SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if I understand correctly, you want to get each user's highest score and return a query in descending order by score.

In that case I would use a CTE with a windows function like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT UserId, Score, gr.Id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By UserId ORDER BY Score DESC) rn
 FROM [dbo].[GameResult] as g
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ticket] as t
      ON (g.TicketId = t.Id)
)
SELECT 
  g1.*, t1.UserId, t1.ControlCode, t1.TicketNumber, u1.UniqueUserId
FROM [dbo].[GameResult] as g1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ticket] as t1
    ON (g1.TicketId = t1.Id)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] as u1
    ON (t1.UserId = u1.Id)
INNER JOIN cte 
    ON g1.Id=cte.Id
WHERE cte.rn = 1
ORDER BY g1.Score Desc, g1.CreatedTime Asc
```

If necessary, what you want CAN be done without the CTE and ROW_NUMBER function, but it would be a much more convoluted query.  This is a cleaner solution that is easier to read, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a [rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms176102.aspx) to the query. You might want to use [dense_rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173825.aspx) or row_number depending on how you want to treat rows with the same score.

Here is a mock-up query:

```
SELECT 
  rank() over (partition by g1.Id order by g1.Score Desc) as Rank,
  g1.Id,
  g1.GameId,
  g1.TicketId,
  g1.Score,
  g1.Email,
  g1.Extra,
  g1.CreatedTime,
  t1.UserId, 
  t1.ControlCode, 
  t1.TicketNumber, 
  u1.UniqueUserId
FROM [dbo].[GameResult] as g1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ticket] as t1
    ON (g1.TicketId = t1.Id)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] as u1
    ON (t1.UserId = u1.Id)
GROUP BY u1.UniqueUserId 
ORDER BY g1.Score Desc, g1.CreatedTime Asc
```

The rank query provided is based on the example data but most likely you will have to calculate the rank over each game, something like this :

```
rank() over (partition by g1.GameId, g1.Id order by g1.Score Desc) as Rank,
```

Answer (score -1):

use Inner join  for more info about [SQL join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) 
example

```
SELECT * FROM GameResult as a 
    INNER JOIN Ticket as b
    ON a.TicketId=b.TicketId;
    INNER JOIN User as c
    ON b.UserId = c.Id
```

Comment: Combine them is the easy part. I want to get the list based on unique user id, see the edit in my post.